# C graph .Can't add edge to the adjacency list

Tags: c, pointers, graph, structure

I am trying to create graph and **addEdge** function is not working.
There is the code I used

```
typedef struct node {
    int v;
    struct node *next;
}node;
void addEdge(node *adj[],int v,int w){
    node t={v,adj[w]};adj[w]=&t;
    node tt={w,adj[v]};adj[v]=&tt;   
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description and there's not enough code to understand or reproduce the problem. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: The nodes `t` and `tt` expire when the function returns, making the pointers to them stored in `adj` invalid.

Comment: Like Arkku said; tt and t are locally instantiated and the pointer is invalid on return (because the allocated memory is on the stack)

Comment: We need a [mcve], but at least the code that calls `addEdge` and the relevant variable declarations. Otherwise the previous 3 comments apply.

Comment: thanks. you pointed out the exact thing.  @Arkku

Answer (score 1):

The nodes `t` and `tt` expire when the function returns, making the pointers to them stored in `adj` invalid.

-Arkku

use malloc.

```
void addEdge(node *adj[],int v,int w){
    node *t = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));  
    t->v=v;t->next=adj[w];adj[w]=t;   
    t=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    t->v=w;t->next=adj[v];adj[v]=t;
}
```

Important: Initialise every element of `node *adj[]` to `NULL`